# Grails automatically reopen connection on fail

Tags: hibernate, grails, jdbc, ingres

I have a Grails app communicating with an ingres database via domain classes. When the database crashes or I restarted it while the application is running I get an Exception:

```
| Error Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Connection failed.
```

This exception then comes every time and forever when I access the database altough the database is back again from restart/crash.

How can I force Grails / Hibernate to recreate a connection or set it to recreate automatically.

This is my config:

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = 'validate'
    url = "jdbc:ingres://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:II7/test"
    driverClassName = "com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver"
    username = "ingres"
    password = "ingres"
    jmxEnabled = true
    initialSize = 5
    maxActive = 50
    minIdle = 5
    maxIdle = 25
    maxWait = 10000
    maxAge = 10 * 60000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
    validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
    validationQueryTimeout = 3
    validationInterval = 15000
    testOnBorrow = true
    testWhileIdle = true
    testOnReturn = true
    jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
    defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was easy to fix after hours of searching and missing the key information.

In my initial config in my question there was no `properties {..}` group around datasource settings. The genius Grails config management didn't warn me about that it is needed. Adding it, everything works fine and GORM can recover from lost connections.

Answer (score 1):

Check out autoReconnect parameter:

```
dataSource {
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true"
        }
```

Another properties, which may be helpful:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "secret"
    password = "santa"

   properties {
      maxActive = 50
      maxIdle = 25
      minIdle = 1
      initialSize = 1

      numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
      maxWait = 10000

      testOnBorrow = true
      testWhileIdle = true
      testOnReturn = true

      validationQuery = "select now()"

      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1000 * 60 * 5
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1000 * 60 * 5
   }
}
```

Comment: I didn't  use the `properties {}` part in my config (see question). Is it necessary?

Comment: `validationQuery = "select now()"`: `now()` is not available on ingress. Use `select 1` instead.

Comment: `autoReconnect` URL parameter is not available for Ingres JDBC driver. It works for mySQL though.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException` indicates that last statement that may have caused DB to crash was automatically rolled back by the DB because of deadlock or other transaction serialization failures.

The fact that restart does not resolve this issue, could be driver specific issue. It seems that the `SQLState` is not being reset (may still contain value '40', or whatever the vendor specific value could be).

Perhaps the main focus should be to pin point the cause of DB crash, on application level. Restarting DB server while application is running is bad practice any way.